# scala implicit question: I have a method to return multiple values, can I set one of the returned values to an implicit value?

Tags: scala

//example, I want to make val2 as an implicit,

//val2 will be used later as an implicit value

`implicit val (val1, val2) = returnMultipleValuesMethod()`

 //but I don't want val1 be an implicit

 is a better way (only want val2 be an implicit)?

Comment: There is no quick syntax for that, just do: `val (val1, val2) = returnMultipleValuesMethod()` and then `implicit val _val2 = val2`

Comment: thanks a lot Luis. since val1 and val2 are different objects, seems scala is able to choose val2 properly later in my code. so both my solution and yours are all working. but I am looking for a better solution. seems scala does not have as of now?